# Tabbed Nav Not showing Content

Tags: html, css, tabs, navigation

Can someone help me, I'm at my wits end.  I've created a CSS3 tabbed nav set up.  When the tab is clicked it should be showing the base content -- at this point it's only one line.  I'm missing something and I just can't see it.  I'm not looking to implement JS or Jquery this should work but it's not.

Here's the code:

```css
.tabs
{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 75px auto;
  list-style: none;
  float: none;
}

.tabs input[type="radio"]
{
  display: none;
}

.tabs label
{
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 160px;
  display:block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans';
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  box-shadow: 0.5px -2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0.5px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  top: 2px;
}

.tabs label:hover
{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  top:0;
}

.tab-content
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

[id^=tab]:checked+label
{
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  top:0;
}

[id^=tab]:checked~[id^=tab-content]
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab1" checked />
  <label for="tab1">Personal Information</label>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tab1-content">Here is the content for tab 1</div>
 </li>
 
 
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab2" />
  <label for="tab2">Academic Information</label>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tab2-content">Here is the content for tab 2</div>
 </li>
 
 
 
 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id="tab3" />
  <label for="tab3">OECTA Involvement</label>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tab3-content">Here is the content for tab 3</div>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only your last css selector

```
[id^=tab]:checked~.tab-content{
    display: block;
}
```

[id^=tab-content] selects all elements with an attribute ID starting with *tab-content* which is not what you want.

Comment: ohhhh So I was looking for the class but forcing it to look for an ID which is why my naming would only work in certain situations!  YOU'RE A GENIUS!  Thank you so much!  I can't mark this as correct for another 5 min but I will!

Comment: One more question, is such a syntax as [class^=tab] possible?

Comment: Yes, but the issue with that kind of selector is that it's not really looking for the class name. It is looking for a class attribute starting with tab, so if your element looks like this <div class="other-class tab-content" ></div> It will not work

Comment: Understood. Thanks so much!